# Numpy splitting multidimensional arrays

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array

I have a multidimensional numpy array that I want to split based on a particular column.

Ex. `[[1,0,2,3],[1,2,3,4],[2,3,4,5]]`
Say I want to split this array by the 2nd column with the expression `x <=2`. Then I would get two arrays `[[1,0,2,3],[1,2,3,4]]` and `[[2,3,4,5]]`.

I am currently using this statement, which I don't  think is correct.

```
splits = np.split(S, np.where(S[:, a] <= t)[0][:1]) #splits S based on t

#a is the column number
```

Comment: What's `x<=2`? Is `x` your row number?

Comment: Its just the values in a particular column.

Comment: So when you say 2nd column, you mean 1-based. `[1, 0, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3, 4]` stay together because you compare `0 <= 2` and `2 <= 2`. `[2, 3, 4, 5]` is "split" because you compare `3 <= 2`. Correct?

Comment: @orange Yep exactly that.

Comment: Please see my answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = np.asarray([[1,0,2,3],[1,2,3,4],[2,3,4,5]])
>>> a
array([[1, 0, 2, 3],
       [1, 2, 3, 4],
       [2, 3, 4, 5]])
>>> split1 = a[a[:,1] <= 2, :]
array([[1, 0, 2, 3],
       [1, 2, 3, 4]])
>>> split2 = a[a[:,1] > 2, :]
array([[2, 3, 4, 5]])
```