# Splitting numpy multidimensional array based on indices stored in another array or list

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a numpy multidimensional array with shape = (12,2,3,3)

```
import numpy as np
arr = np.arange(12*2*3*3).reshape((12,2,3,3))
```

I need to select those elements based on the 2nd dimension where the dindices are stored in another list

```
indices = [0,1,0,0,1,1,0,1,1,0,1,1]
```

in one array, and the rest in another array.
the output in either case should be in another array of shape (12,3,3)

```
arr2 = np.empty((arr.shape[0],*arr.shape[-2:]))
```

I could do it using a for loop

```
for i, ii in enumerate(indices):
    arr2[i] = arr[i, indices[ii],...]
```

However, I am searching for a one liner.

When I try indexing using the list as indices

```
test = arr[:,indices,...]
```

I get `test` of shape (12,12,3,3) instead of (12,3,3). Could you help me please?

Comment: My question is similar to this
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35497234/numpy-splitting-multidimensional-arrays
but with indices instead of condition

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `np.arange` for indexing the first dimension:

```
test = arr[np.arange(arr.shape[0]),indices,...]
```

or just the python `range` function:

```
test = arr[range(arr.shape[0]),indices,...]
```